# Prevent multiple T-SQL statements in a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to prevent SQL Server from executing multiple statements at once

For example, T-SQL will execute a statement like the below one with no issues

```
SELECT '1' UPDATE x SET y = 'z'
```

So if you've a String variable and you only want a SELECT to be performed, is it possible to validate that this string contains only a SELECT statement without searching through it for all possible keywords

Comment: If you're trying to allow arbitrary code but prevent malicious usage, be aware that there are plenty of malicious things one can do just writing a `SELECT` (e.g. cartesian joining a moderately sized table to itself 20 times with the `TABLOCKX` hint applied). Your best defence, however, if you accept that risk, is to *run it under an account that only has `SELECT` permissions*. Then you don't have to build an elaborate parser, etc.

Comment: Seems, if I am honest, you have an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) here. Why are you letting your users enter arbitrary SQL strings into a variable to be executed in the first place?

Comment: We are aware of the implications of allowing arbitrary SQL to be run, but without getting into the details, you can assume that this is a constraint that we have to live with for now.

Comment: It is possible to validate a string variable contains a single SQL statement in app code using a [T-SQL script DOM library](https://www.dbdelta.com/microsoft-sql-server-script-dom/) but there isn't a way to disallow a multi-statement batch via a server config setting. That would break a lot of stuff.

Comment: This is typically the wrong problem to solve; single statements can cause plenty of trouble on their own. The statement that you are "aware" of the implications is rather easily disproven if you then have to ask how to prevent multi-statement batches, because those are not the issue -- the fact that you have to have a foolproof way of parsing T-SQL statements to match them up with "safe" and "allowed" patterns is. (Per Dan, you do need the complete parser for this -- just the shenanigans you can get up to using comments require it.)

Comment: So, presumably, you already have processes in place to stop users from running malicious SQL, @Neil ? If not, you'll need to get that in place before you apply an arbitrary requirement like only being able to have one statement in the submitted batch.

Comment: @Larnu the application in question is old, and the option to allow users to send SELECT statements to the database has been active for a long time. The database in question is not critical to the running of the application and at most contains info that I consider low sensitivity (no passwords, personal data etc.). Most queries are generated by a server and are safe, but there is this one API endpoint which allows users with specific permissions to send supposedly read-only queries to the database for their own reporting. My job is to find a way to tighten this up as it's not fit for purpose

Comment: Sounds like you should be fixing the root of the problem then, if I am honest. That *will* fix the problem.

Comment: So just change their user roles to `db_datareader`, and take them out of any other role. Then the only thing they can do is `SELECT`. You are simply approaching this wrong.

Comment: I absolutely agree with the solution of restricting permissions for these commands and have upticked the first comment here. This, along with removing the API endpoint if possible will be my recommendation. I was simply answering the questions of the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

**You should change the roles of the users** to include just `public` and `db_datareader`, and take them out of any other role.

Then the only thing they can do is `SELECT` queries.